# Displaying angularJS scope element in HTML

Tags: angularjs

I have `$scope.policyNumber` in my angularJS, that holds the `value` of a `key` obtained from a json, which needs to be displayed in this segment:

```
<div id="alert_failure" class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible"
                    role="alert" style="display: none;">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"
                        aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <strong>Snap!</strong> SourceID/s {{policyNumber}} is/are already present in OVERRIDE table.
                </div>
```

My UI displays

> Snap! SourceID/s is/are already present in OVERRIDE table.

without returning the policyNumber.

Is there a way this could be achieved?

**JS function**:

```
$scope.submit = function(employees) {
                $http({
                    'url' : '/updateOverride',
                    'method' : 'POST',
                    'headers' : {
                        'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
                    },
                    'data' : $scope.employees
                }).then(function(employees) {
                    $scope.insertResult = employees.data;
                        var controllerMessage = $scope.insertResult;
                        var messageKey = 'result';
                        var result = controllerMessage[messageKey];
                        console.log(controllerMessage); 
                        if(result == "success"){
                        } else {
                            var dataKey = 'data';
                            var policyData = controllerMessage[dataKey];
                            $scope.policyNumber = policyData;
                            console.log($scope.policyNumber);
                        }
                        $("#alert_"+result).show()
                })
            };
```

Comment: What is the JSON response you are getting from above request?

Comment: {result: "failure", data: "CAH3105090819"}

Comment: I think your submit function call by somewhere then webservice get result and everything will be fine then below code will works for you,
$http.post(Server.url + "updateOverride/", {
                transformResponse: function (response)
                {
                    return response;
                }
            }).then(function (response) {
                $scope.policyNumber = response.data;
            });

Comment: Yes this is what I assumed. Either you are not making correct request or  some other server side issue. Check what `CAH3105090819` mean at server side.

Comment: That is a catch ! Must check it. Thanks Chandrakant & VicJordan. Btw, Chandrakant, I suppose you have added a few extra braces. Can you pls recheck so that I can try it?